# What percentage of a cut is it fair for a freelance platform to take, for gigs that are short, independent stints?

Tags: payments

I have worked on a freelance platform (won't name it) to do some tech writing. They are transparent on charging a 25% fee per assignment. Even if you newly join, you can write a tech post and get paid the amount the client paid, minus 25% of the platform's fee.

However, there are other platforms which pay you lesser than what the client pays, and they promise to assess you periodically to see if you can move to a higher payment band, based on how good your work is and/or how many projects you've done on the platform. I've seen this not just for writing services, but also for interview-as-a-service (freelance software engineers interview other engineers) platforms.

On one such interview-as-a-service platform, their website says they charge clients **$25** per interview. That's **Rs.1940** as of today. However, they offered me only Rs.700 per interview. So they were taking **64%** of a cut from the amount. Compared to this, there are two other interview-as-a-service companies that offer freelancers $100 per interview (which sounds too-good-to-be-true). Another platform also offered only Rs.700, and another one offered only Rs.400 to Rs.500. I don't know how much they charged clients, and when I asked, they refused to answer it too. Since I saw these as red-flags, I didn't proceed with any of them.

Similarly, a company that offered freelancers opportunities to do trainings in various companies, told me they'd take **30%** of the payments as their cut. A friend later told me that's less, because the company that offered her training opportunities, took **40%** of a cut.

Answers [here](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/272/should-a-contractor-charge-a-higher-hourly-rate-for-a-shorter-term-contract-rul) indicate that it's ok for contractors to charge higher for short stints. Shouldn't online platforms only charge a "[finders fee](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/questions/3978/finders-fee-or-percentage-for-a-6-months-contract)" of around 10% or 20%...or a max of 30%? Do the companies really have so much of overhead costs that they need to charge higher than 30%, or are they being greedy and exploitative?

What is a fair percentage for a cut, and in what situations/job-types would various percentages apply? What has your experience been with various clients/platforms? What did they charge and why?

Comment: I signed up to serveral to take a look and it did not look like something for me to spend time on. Extremly low prices and a huge provision without providing any services except "we got one job listed for you and other can compete with you to get" im now using a company that is finding jobs and selling me to the customer. They charge only 10% and they provide good services and actually do work for their money.

Comment: 10% is very reasonable. I wonder if we should consider it a red flag if gig platforms refuse to disclose how much they charge the client or if they charge a commission of more than 30% or if they delay payments or if they try to pay based on our experience, regardless of how much they charged the client.

Comment: This is an unanswerable question as "fair" is in the eye of the person. For example, I've seen art galleries that took 60% but they sold a lot. The real question is: is this platform producing a lot of clients that pay well? If they are, then the percentage is not a problem.

Comment: The way commissions go, there is indeed a percentage that can be considered fair, based on how much influence or work each party puts in. your art gallery may be an outlier. Google brings in a lot of ad clients, but they take only 30%. The interview-as-a-service platform pays Rs.700 irrespective of what the client pays. Even if the Rupee decreases in value compared to the dollar, the Rs.700 pay stays same. It's an exploitative strategy. Also, many platforms don't disclose what the client pays (more exploitation)

Comment: **What percentage of a cut is it fair for a freelance platform to take** - There's no concept of fair in a free market. They're free to take whatever cut they choose, regardless of the complexity or duration of the work, and you're free to accept their terms or to not use their platform. Stop thinking in terms of fairness. Set your market price for your services and then decide if you're willing to live with whatever cut they take. If you're not then don't use them.

Comment: @joeqwerty: I agree, but even in a free market (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_market), there are prohibitions (and for good reason). Salaried people and freelancers know of how pay disparity happens when there's a lack of knowledge of what the median pay is for a job. That's where sites like payscale.com helped. The take-it-or-leave-it concept can be presented by the employer or employee, based on supply and demand. The knowledge of what's fair/reasonable (based on the company or context) helps decide whether to take-it-or-leave-it. That knowledge is what I'm asking for.